# InfoWindow is displayed 2 times instead of once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To explain what I am doing, I want to display the `InfoWindowF` when I click on a marker on the map, same thing when I click on store locations on the list of all the stores.
The issue I am facing, is when I click on a Marker, the InfoWindowF will be displayed 2 times, that means both conditionals renders are true, I only want to display the `InfoWindowF` once, either when the marker is clicked or when the store location is clicked.
Code:

```
const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState<any>(null);
  const [infoWindowContent, setInfoWindowContent] = useState<string | null>(
    null,
  );
  const [isSelectedStore, setIsSelectedStore] = useState<any>(null);
  const [SelectedInfoWindowContent, setSelectedInfoWindowContent] = useState<
    string | null
  >(null);
  const handleMarkerClick = (location: Location) => {
    setSelectedRegion({
      region: location.country,
      geoLocation: location.geo,
      id: location._id,
      name: location.name,
    });
    setSelectedMarker(location);
    setInfoWindowContent(location.name);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedStore) {
      setIsSelectedStore(selectedStore);
      setSelectedInfoWindowContent(selectedStore.name);
    }
  }, [selectedStore]);
return(
 <GoogleMap
     ...
    >
      <Marker ... />
     {selectedMarker && (
        <InfoWindowF
          position={selectedMarker.geo}
          onCloseClick={() => setSelectedMarker(null)}
        >
          <div>{infoWindowContent}</div>
        </InfoWindowF>
      )}
      {!selectedMarker && isSelectedStore && SelectedInfoWindowContent && (
        <InfoWindowF
          position={isSelectedStore.geoLocation}
          onCloseClick={() => setIsSelectedStore(false)}
        >
          <div>{SelectedInfoWindowContent}</div>
        </InfoWindowF>
      )}
```

This is where the problem is coming from :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedStore) {
      setIsSelectedStore(selectedStore);
      setSelectedInfoWindowContent(selectedStore.name);
    }
  }, [selectedStore]);
```

how can I fix this